# Contour plot of image gives: TypeError Input must be 2D array error

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, matplotlib, scipy

I am using Debian Linux and python 2.7.
I am reading an image and trying to process it but I am being shown the following error. Can someone please tell me what i'm doing wrong?

```
import Image
import scipy
from scipy import ndimage
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy import misc
import scipy.misc

img = scipy.misc.imread("/home/subhradeep/Desktop/test.jpg")
array=np.asarray(img)
plt.figure(figsize=(10, 3.6))

plt.subplot(131)
plt.imshow(array, cmap=plt.cm.gray)

plt.subplot(132)
plt.imshow(array, cmap=plt.cm.gray, vmin=10, vmax=100)
plt.axis('off')

plt.subplot(133)
plt.imshow(array, cmap=plt.cm.gray)
plt.contour(array, [160, 211])
plt.axis('off')

plt.subplots_adjust(wspace=0, hspace=0., top=0.99, bottom=0.01, left=0.05,right=0.99)
plt.show()
```

I get the following error message

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "1saveimg.py", line 22, in <module>
    plt.contour(array, [160, 211])
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 2632, in contour
    ret = ax.contour(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/axes.py", line 7976, in contour
    return mcontour.QuadContourSet(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/contour.py", line 1414, in __init__
    ContourSet.__init__(self, ax, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/contour.py", line 860, in __init__
    self._process_args(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/contour.py", line 1427, in _process_args
    x, y, z = self._contour_args(args, kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/contour.py", line 1488, in _contour_args
    x, y = self._initialize_x_y(z)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/contour.py", line 1573, in _initialize_x_y
    raise TypeError("Input must be a 2D array.")
TypeError: Input must be a 2D array.
```

I also tried `Image.open()` but that too throws the same error.

Comment: What error you have with this code?

Comment: Always copy and paste the full error traceback into the question itself (as opposed to putting only the error message into the title).  After changing the image filename and fixing the copy/paste error `le$`, your code seems to work for me.

Comment: @DSM what changes should I make to the image filename? Are you asking to replace all instnaces of array with img?

Comment: No, I mean that obviously I don't have a picture at `/home/subhradeep/Desktop/test.jpg`, so I had to change it to one of my own.  However, it turned out that the reason my test worked was because the `jpg` file I chose at random happened to be black and white. :^)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem here is that `plt.contour` only plots 2d arrays, but most `jpg` files are 3d, because there are three colors.  You've hidden this fact by plotting with a grayscale colormap (`cm.gray`), which just changes how it looks (`imshow` is still showing a color image, just printing it in gray 'ink').  You have a couple options, mainly:

1) Somehow convert it to 2d, most simply by making the image black and white (grayscale).  Here are a few ways to do it:

```
gray = img.sum(-1)  # sums along the last (color) axis
```

or

```
gray = np.sqrt((img*img).sum(-1)) # to do a magnitude of the color vector
```

or

```
from PIL import Image
img = Image.open("/home/subhradeep/Desktop/test.jpg")
gray = img.convert('L')   # 'L' stands for 'luminosity'
gray = np.asarray(gray)
```

2) Plot each color separately:

```
r, g, b = np.rollaxis(img, -1)
plt.contour(r, cmap=plt.cm.Reds)
plt.contour(g, cmap=plt.cm.Greens)
plt.contour(b, cmap=plt.cm.Blues)
```

---

Also,

`scipy.misc.imread` returns an array, so you can skip the line `arr = np.asarray(img)` and just use `img` as it is.  This isn't true if you decide to use `PIL.Image`, which returns a `PIL.Image` object (hence being able to use the `img.convert` method).

Doing this is redundant, just pick one or the other:

```
from scipy import misc
import scipy.misc
```

---

Here if you convert to grayscale:
[image: gray]

And, if you plot each color separately:
[image: rgb]

Comment: Thank you so much for clearing all my doubts at once. Couldn't have got a better explaination than this. Now I got all my concepts clear.

Comment: I tried plotting each color separately as you suggested but then I get this 

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "1saveimg.py", line 23, in <module>
    r, g, b = np.rollaxis(img, -1)
ValueError: too many values to unpack


What am I doing wrong now

Comment: Hm, can you tell me what `img.shape` is?  That line assumes that it is something like `(H, W, 3)` where `H, W` are your height and width of your image, and `3` is the number of colors.  The `rollaxis` just changes the shape to `(3, H, W)`, so that `r, g, b = ...` is equivalent to `r = np.rollaxis(img, -1)[0]; g = np.rollaxis(img, -1)[1]` and so on.  Maybe it's simpler just to ignore the `rollaxis` and do `plt.contour(img[...,0]); plt.contour(img[...,1])` and so on